# Array : use object ID as a key

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have an array of WP_Post on my Wordpress website.

I need to use the post ID as a key in an array (to use a `isset($array[$id])` condition).

What is the cleanest way to achieve something like this :

```
$tmp = [];
foreach($playlist_videos as $p) {
    $tmp[$p->ID] = $p;
}
```

I'm using PHP 7.1, so I thought using *array_column*, but it will only return one of object properties

Comment: Can you post more of your code? Where is the `isset`? How are you getting your posts?

Comment: It's not quite clear from this example what your original object is, but try something like this  $vars = get_object_vars ( $playlist_videos );
foreach($vars as $key=>$value)

Comment: if you try to convert an object to an array , you can also try $array = (array) $yourObject;